# Mouse move event on a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have an TableLayoutPanel object.
I want to be able to drag n drop a label in the table layout panel.

I have the following code:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    var formPos = this.PointToClient(tableLayoutPanel1.PointToScreen(e.Location));
    if (!prevPoint.IsEmpty) {
        int deltaX = formPos.X - prevPoint.X;
        int deltaY = formPos.Y - prevPoint.Y;
        lblClass.Location = new Point(lblClass.Location.X + deltaX, lblClass.Location.Y + deltaY);
        prevPoint = formPos;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the MouseMove event fires only when I move the mouse from one cell to another, and doesn't fire when I move the mouse inside a cell.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Since you're moving the Label, wouldn't you need to trap the mouse movement within it when it "snaps" to the new cell?...since it will be below the cursor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: It looks like you're moving the Label as the mouse is moved.  When the Label is under the mouse, the MouseMove() event for the TableLayoutPanel will no longer fire since the cursor is now over the Label.  Therefore the MouseMove() event for the Label should be used instead.  In fact, you'd need to the events for both controls to handle when the mouse is over either of them.  In short, the MouseMove() event will only fire for whatever control the mouse is currently over.